# "Unmatched block nesting" MASM

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

I can not find the error. I'm new to assembly language.I use "MASM" to "DOSBOX" and already made seven successful programs, I only need the latter but can not find my mistake.

```
MODEL TINY

.LISTALL

.386

.CODE

.STARTUP

MOV EAX, 123455H

CALL DISPE

.EXIT

DISPE  PROC NEAR

       MOV EBX, 10

       PUSH BX

       MOV CL, 0

       .WHILE 1

       MOV EDX, 0

       DIV EBX

       ADD DL, 30H

       PUSH DX

       .BREAK .IF EAX==0

       INC CL

       .IF CL==3

       MOV CL, 0

       .ENDIF

       .ENDW

       .WHILE 1

       POP DX

       .BREAK

       MOV AH, 2

       INT 21H

       .ENDW

       RET

DISPE  ENDP

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you indent your code, you would spot the problem right away!!!  Take a look at your proc with "good" indentation...

```
DISPE PROC NEAR
    MOV EBX, 10 
    PUSH BX 
    MOV CL, 0

    .WHILE 1    
        MOV EDX, 0  
        DIV EBX 
        ADD DL, 30H
        PUSH DX
        .BREAK 

        .IF EAX==0  
            INC CL

        .IF CL==3   
            MOV CL, 0   
        .ENDIF  
    .ENDW

    .WHILE 1    
        POP DX  
        .BREAK

        MOV AH, 2       
        INT 21H 
    .ENDW

    RET
DISPE ENDP
```

Spot what is missing?  You have 2 `.if`s but only one `.endif`.  Might be a typo on your part, maybe the second `.if` was supposed to be an `.elseif` or `.else`?